# continuebrowsing without waiting output to php

Tags: php

I currently submit a process to a class.php page doing some calculations, which get written to a MySql database for the users to use.
Depending on the clients internet speed the calculation do take long and the user is waiting for it to finish.
Is there a way to submit the process and allow the users to continue browsing while it finish in the background.

The calculation only need to be submitted once a week

I have 
rank.php

inside it    $ranklist=$admin->do_ranking()

then inside admin.class

function do-ranking(){

the calculations
}
return $ranking
}

Comment: Something like `ignore_user_abort()`? I'm not sure of php supports sending task to background thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two wide spread strategies for this:

1. send response early and detach

You can send the response (whatever that is, might also be empty) right away and forward the task to be computed to a background task. Several options for that, either based on a cron task periodically checking for waiting jobs to be computed. So we are talking about a simple job scheduler, you will find easy examples for that. Or you can spawn a system process and detach from that. how exactly depends on the operating system you use, on Linux for example you can push the process into background, thus return immediately to the spawning php script.

2. use a ajax request to transmit the data

This certainly is the much more elegant approach: instead of doing a full page reload at all (by sending a form form example) you use some simple client side logic (read: javascript) to send the data (or an empty request) via an ajax request. That means the page loaded into the browser is not unloaded at all and the user can do whatever he likes.

Comment: Tx , I went for option 2. I should have think of that too, but still learning php and the ajax stuff. I submiited the ajax request when the page load .